# NSInvocationOperation and AmazonServiceRequestDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file-upload, amazon-s3

My application creates an S3PutObjectRequest within a method called from NSInvocationOperation.  The PutObjectRequests delegate is the view controller for that view.  If I remove the delegate, the put request completes successfully.  However, when I try to use

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:    
(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
```

by adding the delegate, it never completes and I can't access the file I was trying to upload.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When using `AmazonServiceRequestDelegate`, [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3RYJD3PLLN161/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Asynchronously-Part-II-AmazonRequestDelegate-Best-Prac) can be helpful. The first recommendation from the post applies to your case:

- Avoid using AmazonServiceRequestDelegate in a background thread

`NSInvocationOperation` automatically creates a background thread, and the `NSRunLoop` that is responsible for calling the delegate methods disappears when the background thread finishes processing.